# How can I change my code to use background workers instead of background threads

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, backgroundworker

I have a winform application making API requests and writing the responses to text boxes.  The requests can take a few minutes to complete and to prevent the application freezing up on each API request I'm using background threads.  However I would like to use background workers instead to avoid the large number of delegates needed for each form control.  How can I change my code to use background workers instead?

I've looked around and most of the information I found on background workers are related to progress bars and I can't work out how to use background workers for what I'm doing.

```
 private delegate void TextBox1WriteDelegate(string i);
    private void TextBox1Write(string i)
    {
        textBox1.Text = i;
    }

    public void GetApiData()
    {
        using (HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient())
        {
            var response = httpClient.GetAsync("http://apiendpoint.com").Result;
            textBox1.Invoke(new TextBox1WriteDelegate(TextBox1Write), response.RequestMessage.ToString());
        }
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Thread t = new Thread(GetApiData);
        t.IsBackground = true;
        t.Start();
    }
```

Comment: Have you looked up Background Worker? There are examples on the internet (e.g. in the docs of BW).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's easy enough to do the Background worker.. as such:

```
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        BackgroundWorker bw = new BackgroundWorker();

        bw.DoWork += (a, b) => GetApiData();
    }
```

But, that doesn't necessarily fix the delegate issue...

To eliminate the defined delegate, change GetApiData() to be:

```
    public void GetApiData()
    {
        using (HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient())
        {
            var response = httpClient.GetAsync("http://apiendpoint.com").Result;
            textBox1.Invoke((Action)delegate 
            { 
              textBox1.Text = response.RequestMessage.ToString(); 
            });
        }
    }
```

You can then eliminate the delegate definition.

You could go also go all the way and do this:

```
    private void button3_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        BackgroundWorker bw = new BackgroundWorker();

        bw.DoWork += (a, b) =>
        {
            using (HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient())
            {
                var response = httpClient.GetAsync("http://apiendpoint.com").Result;
                textBox1.Invoke((Action)delegate 
                { 
                   textBox1.Text = response.RequestMessage.ToString(); 
                });
            }
        };
    }
```

Eliminating all of the functions. Depends on whether you are going to reuse GetAPI data somewhere else

Comment: BTW, as Joe noted, I answered this question by looking up "BackgroundWorker" and "Invoke Lambda".